# Deserialize data from nested dict stored in a json with JsonUtility

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a json that stores the reachable coordinates based on a distance for each of the coordinates of a board. In this json I have a nested list, provided by Python that looks like this:

```
posibleMovementsByDistance : 
    [
        [
            [
                {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0},
                {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0}
            ], 
            [
                {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 1},
                {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 1},
                {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0}
            ],
            [
                {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 1}
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0},
                {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 0}
            ], 
            [
                {"x": 3, "y": 0, "z": 1},
                {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 1},
                {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 0}
            ],
            [
                {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 1}
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I am trying to read this information in C# and testing from:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class GameMapTester
{
    [SerializeField] List<List<List<Vector3Int>>> posibleMovementsByDistance;
};

public class MapTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset jsonData;
    public GameMapTester gameMap;
    public void Awake()
    {
        jsonData = Resources.Load("Maps/MapsCreators/BaseMap") as TextAsset;
        gameMap = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameMapTester>(jsonData.text);
    }
};
```

To another options with objects like:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TileLevelTwo
{
    public List<TileInfo> neighbor;
};

[System.Serializable]
public class TileLevelOne
{
    public List<TileLevelTwo> tileLevelTwo;
};

[System.Serializable]
public class TileInfo
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
};

[System.Serializable]
public class GameMapTester
{
    [SerializeField] public List<TileLevelOne> posibleMovementsByDistance;
};

public class MapTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset jsonData;
    public GameMapTester gameMap;
    public void Awake()
    {
        jsonData = Resources.Load("Maps/MapsCreators/BaseMap") as TextAsset;
        gameMap = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameMapTester>(jsonData.text);
    }
};
```

And multiple others similar options (nested arrays, nested objects...)

At this point, the unity documentation says:

> Note: Unity doesn’t support serialization of multilevel types (multidimensional arrays, jagged arrays, dictionaries, and nested container types). If you want to serialize these, you have two options:
>
> - Wrap the nested type in a class or struct
> - Use serialization callbacks, by implementing ISerializationCallbackReceiver, to perform custom serialization.

I don't know what else to try, does anyone know how I can deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Unity but it seems that its built-in (de)serialization capabilities aren't as fully featured as they could be. Fortunately the library [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) can deserialize structures like this for you.

```
jsonData = Resources.Load("Maps/MapsCreators/BaseMap") as TextAsset;
gameMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameMapTester>(jsonData.text);
```